# Changing sign of number when transposing

Tags: recreational-mathematics, transpose

In an equation, when we change a variable or number sides, we change its sign from positive to negative and vice-versa, right?

So in `738 = a + b`, shouldn't it be: `-a = -738 + b`? Or at least: `a = -738 + b` as opposed to what chatgpt is telling me

> No, you seem to have made a mistake. If you start with (738 = a + b), and you want to isolate (a), you should subtract (b) from both sides, not add it. The correct step would be (a = 738 - b).

The answer visually makes sense... But what about the rule of transposing and changing numbers sign?

I tried solving it online.. `738 = a + b`, solving for `a`, it tells me `a = (-738)/(-1)` I don't understand...

Quoting another website..

> To solve 2x –3 = 13 by transposing, we do the following:
>
> Instead of adding 3 to both sides,we can transpose the 3 that’s
> already there by
>
> moving it from the left side, over the equal sign, to the right side,
> and changing its sign from “–” to “+.”   Now we have  2x = 13 + 3

Comment: Do not use ChatGPT as a sole math source.

Comment: Additionally, please use MathJax to format your posts.

Comment: Chat GPT is horrible at doing math. For your own sake, don't consult it about math. For our sake, don't ask us to debug its output.

Comment: Who online told you the following? *"I tried solving it online.. `738 = a + b`, solving for `a`, it tells me `a = (-738)/(-1)`"* I also don't understand how or why...

Comment: @peterwhy this site and 2 other.. https://scanftree.com/math/calculator/transposition-equations-solver --- in the first field I put "738=a+b" and the 2nd "a" (solve for a)

Comment: @SeanRoberson did you read the post? I used a quote from one site, mentioned that I got the answer "a = (-738)/(-1)" from other 3 sites, and used chatgpt for other input before coming to stackexchange, so that's 4 sources my guy

Comment: Apart from your "rule of transposing and changing numbers sign", you should also know that $=$ is symmetric, e.g. in this case $738 = a+b$ may be rewritten as $a+b = 738$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend that learners not think of mathematical operations in terms of their *cosmetic* outcomes (which side of the equation they're on, for example); that just leads to misremembered rules and an inability to understand why rules are valid. Instead, think of the mathematical operations themselves. For example, *we are allowed to subtract the same quantity from both sides of an equation*.

So if we start from $738=a+b$, we are allowed to subtract $a$ from both sides of the equation, yielding $738-a = a+b-a$ or simply $738-a=b$. From there, subtracting $738$ from both sides of the equation yields $738-a-738=b-738$, or simply $-a=b-738$ (which you correctly found).

ChatGPT's answer is also correct (this time...): subtracting $b$ from both sides of the original equation does yield $738-b=a$. (Wherever $a = (-738)/(-1)$ came from, it's not correct in general.)